# linq expression does not work with where inside foreach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, lambda

Why as this one works:

```
@foreach (var p in Model.Where(pages => pages.IsTopMenu == true))
{ @p.PageName }
```

Where as this does not:

```
@foreach (var p in Model)
{  @p.PageName.Where(pages => pages.IsTopMenu == true)
}
```

With second expr. Can not resolve IsTopMenu

Comment: Assuming `PageName` is a `string`, your `Where` is performed on  `char[]`, so your `pages` parameter is actually a `char` which obviously doesn't have the `IsTopMenu` property. What's wrong with the first snippet?

Comment: I need to write different where caluese on same model. If I write at beggining in forewach loop start tags, If won not let me for other where clauses.

Comment: I will probably need to add a wrapper for pages like navigation. I will try thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Because Model is a list while in second expression you are trying to apply where on a single object which is not acceptable.

Comment: Because I wanted to add some more where claues in same foreach loop like: IsTopMenu, IsForwardedPage etc. if I do that in begging, other where clauses will not be possible. Or should I find better way?

Comment: You need to know that where or select only works on Ienumerable,list and IQueryable or we can say it works on collections not on single object so if you can tell me what you exactly trying to achieve then maybe I can help you.

Comment: Ok I got the point. Will find some other way. I am new to this sorry.

Comment: I thought if statement would help. But it would not. I am trying to build a menu with dropdown submenus. Like:

`
@model List<DropDownMenu.Models.Pages>
@foreach (var p in Model)
[some css stuff here for top menu]
                { @p.PageName.Where(c=>c.IsTopMenu == true) }
[some css stuff here for sub menus]
{ @p.PageName.Where(c=>c.IsSubMenu == true) }
`
etc.. if I add where clause in beggining, I would not be able to reach IsSubMenu.

Comment: you need to have model like this : a string for menu and a list of submenus then post a list of root model in the view